# laravel group by date show 0 when no data for the charts

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, chart.js, laravel-8

What I want to use this is for a chartjs line chart in dashboard.

```
$today = today();
$dates = [];

for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
$dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('Y-m-d');
}

$year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
$month = Carbon::now()->format('m');
$daysCount = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, 1)->daysInMonth;


$exportsdefault = Shipment::select(DB::raw("COUNT(id) as count "), DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date') )
            ->Where('shipment_type' ,'Export')
            ->where('company_id',2)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2022-10-01', '2022-10-31'])
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->pluck('count');

$exports = array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(0,$daysCount), 0), $exportsdefault->toArray());
```

---

The output which I'm getting is as follows

---

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => 5
  1 => 3
  2 => 2
  3 => 10
  4 => 1
  5 => 4
  6 => 1
  7 => 2
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
  12 => 0
  13 => 0
  14 => 0
  15 => 0
  16 => 0
  17 => 0
  18 => 0
  19 => 0
  20 => 0
  21 => 0
  22 => 0
  23 => 0
  24 => 0
  25 => 0
  26 => 0
  27 => 0
  28 => 0
  29 => 0
  30 => 0
  31 => 0
]
```

Where it groups all the data according to the dates and shows in the beginning.

What I want is to show 0 when there is no data.
for example :

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 5
  2 => 0
  3 => 3
  4 => 10
  5 => 0
  6 => 1
  7 => 4
  8 => 1
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
  12 => 0
  13 => 0
  14 => 0
  15 => 0
  16 => 2
  17 => 0
  18 => 0
  19 => 0
  20 => 0
  21 => 0
  22 => 0
  23 => 0
  24 => 0
  25 => 0
  26 => 0
  27 => 0
  28 => 0
  29 => 0
  30 => 0
  31 => 0
]
```

---

According to the dates of the month to shown in a line chart

---

Comment: What do you get when you dump `$exportsdefault`

Comment: hi @Grant , I'm getting the following
`#items: array:8 [▼
    0 => 5
    1 => 3
    2 => 2
    3 => 10
    4 => 1
    5 => 4
    6 => 1
    7 => 2
  ]`

Comment: It's the grouping, there are no rows for certain dates so they are mitigated, maybe you could do a subquery?

Comment: Hi @Grant  no luck